# Map-merge при наличии List в качестве значений

Tags: java, коллекции, map

Задача следующая - есть мапа, которая хранит в себе Id и связанный с ним список значений.

```
private Map<Integer, List<Meal>> repository = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Override
public Meal save(Integer userId, Meal meal) {
    List<Meal> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(meal);
    //write your code there
    return null;
}
```

Необходимо написать lamda-функцию для утильного метода мапы merge(), чтобы при обращении к методу в List определенной пары добавить meal из аргументов. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 0):

Тут, похоже, имеется ввиду, что в лямбду надо **remappingFunction** свернуть. Что-то типа того:

```
Map<Integer, List<Meal>> repository = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

repository.put(1, new ArrayList<>());

Integer integer = 2;
List<Meal> mealList = new ArrayList<>();

repository.merge(integer, mealList, (mealList1, mealList2) -> {
    mealList1.addAll(mealList2);
    return mealList1;
});

System.out.println(repository); // {1=[], 2=[]}
```

Comment: имеется ввиду, что после добавления ключа в виде 1 у него в виде значений может быть список чисел - 1,2,3,4 и т.д.
Допустим - у меня уже есть пара 1 и список с вышеуказанными числами, но в метод пришло число 5 и его нужно добавить в эту пару, чтобы получился ключ 1 и список "1,2,3,4,5"